# Discord.js Writing to a JSON File with Channel Message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, format

Im trying to create a -transcript command for my bot using [discord-fetch-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-fetch-all) as I thought it would be easier than fetching 100 messages at a time (I also dont really know how to do that). I got my code working, as in it logs everything to my ticket.json file, but its a COMPLETE mess! I dont really know how to format it (I assume its not a part of the npm right?). So I was wondering if I could have some help? Really all I want it to log is `TIMESTAMP | AUTHOR: "MESSAGE'` my current code:

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const fetchAll = require('discord-fetch-all');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    name: 'transcript',
    description: "logs the ticket transcript!",
    
    async execute(message, args) {

        const channel = message.channel

        const allMessages = await fetchAll.messages(channel, {
            reverseArray: true, 
            userOnly: false, 
            botOnly: false, 
            pinnedOnly: false, 
        });

        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `ticket`), JSON.stringify(allMessages));
    }}
```

and an example of what my ticket.json looks like:

```
[{"channelID":"864239107161063434","deleted":false,"id":"864239107592290314","type":"DEFAULT","system":false,"content":"**Channel Nuked**","authorID":"844924130759409685","pinned":false,"tts":false,"nonce":null,"embeds":[],"attachments":[],"createdTimestamp":1626121060036,"editedTimestamp":0,"webhookID":null,"applicationID":null,"activity":null,"flags":0,"reference":null,"guildID":"783070743209705494","cleanContent":"**Channel Nuked**"},}
```

except it has one of these for every message in the channel ;(

All help is appreciated... if there is a better way to do this, feel free to let me know.

Comment: You can simply extract the timestamp, author and content for each Message in the allMessages array and output them in a file.

Comment: How can I do that? would it go inside the const allmessages?

Answer (score 0):

You should loop the `allMessages` variable, then you can format it in whatever way you like, for example

```
const results = []
for(let i in array) {
  results.push({
    timestamp: i.timestamp,
    author: i.author,
    message: i.message,
  });
}
fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `ticket`), JSON.stringify(results));
```